# Minimum memory used by jhipster back microservice

Tags: spring-boot, optimization, memory, jhipster, quarkus

We have memory problems when we create a lot of back microservices with 6.10.5 jhipsther springboot  (each one with one or two entities).

My questions are:

1. What is the minimum memory necessary for SpringBoot backend jhipster 6.10.5?
2. And with jhipster quarkus?
3. Any alternative, we need have a lot of little microservices...
4. In my example, springboot, can we reduce the memory? Any idea?

An example the last microservice with springboot in his startup:

- Needs => docker memory param: 512m
  With jconsole I can see in startup:
  194M NonHeap
  69 HEAP
  ===========
  258M total => x 2 = 512m RAM

This microservice have:

- 2 entities
- Elastic connector
- JPA with DB2 driver
- Kafka listener (connector)
- Hazelcast
- Connected to Jhipster Registry

Comment: I think 512MB RAM should be good. Spring Boot 2.4 might use less, but we haven't been successful in upgrading to it yet. https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/13551

Micronaut might use less memory too. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/08/17/micronaut-jhipster-heroku

Comment: I'm not sure for 6.10.5 but for small services I usually use `-Xms128m -Xmx256m`, then it depends on so many other parameters so for me the only valid answer is: don't guess, just test. Of course, using containers increase memory requirements